Issue with Elasticsearch plugin installation
I encountered an issue while installing the Elasticsearch plugin by BitBag on our online store. When I attempted to execute the command php bin/console fos:elastica:populate to populate Elasticsearch indices as part of the installation process, I received the error message:

Couldn't connect to host, Elasticsearch down?

This message suggests a connectivity issue with Elasticsearch. I would greatly appreciate any suggestions for resolving this issue.

What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck? Is this problem really related to Symfony or Sylius? Did everything work before installing that plugin?

The plugin requires Elasticsearch running on your server or dev machine. Once it is running make sure the given environment variable is provided:
ELASTICSEARCH_URL=http://localhost:9200

or if you are using Docker:
ELASTICSEARCH_URL=http://elasticsearch:9200


The current environment variables used by the latest version (currently v3.2.4) of the plugin are:
BITBAG_ES_HOST=http://localhost
BITBAG_ES_PORT=9200

or if you are using Docker:
BITBAG_ES_HOST=http://elasticsearch
BITBAG_ES_PORT=9200

(see https://github.com/BitBagCommerce/SyliusElasticsearchPlugin/blob/v3.2.4/src/Resources/config/config.yml#L12):
